# Unable to configure Olark chat window to be detached

Tags: javascript, api

I am using the [Olark](https://www.olark.com/) live chat plugin, and I am trying to make changes to the configuration via the API. I pass my configuration to olark as such:

```
const olarkConfig = { 
  hb_detached: true,
  hb_primary_color: '#333333',
  hb_position: 'left',
}
```

I know this works because both the primary color and the position are successfully set. However, the `hb_detached` setting does not seem to work. According to their [docs](https://www.olark.com/api#system_hb_detached) I should be able to set this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Olark was using mobile settings, even up to window sizes of around 1150px for some reason. At a larger window size than this, the `hb_detached` setting kicks in.